# Divide screen to two halves with a title for each and center a view inside each one that will shrink or expand to fill the space

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to create this kind of layout in android.

I'm using constraint layout. I want to divide the screen with height y to two halves with y/2 height each.

Each one of them will have a textview as title which takes the whole width and has constant height.

And a circular custom view which I would like to expand or shrink so it fills the whole half so the padding marked as 'auto' will all be the same but dynamic.

And p will be a minimum padding that the view can't be over them.
The aspect ratio should of those circles should not be changed.
Is that even possible doing it in the xml design editor? or do I have to do it programmatically.
Next step will be to arrange those halves to be side by side if it's a landscape view.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did it, Basically you drag the 4 edges of a each view to center it in the outside element. And set the margins to .
So I dragged title2 to all directions of the screen and it got centered. Then I dragged each of the circular views edges the same way so the upper view I dragged to title1 and the bottom to title2. The bottom view I dragged its top to title 2 and the bottom to the bottom of the screen.
Auto resizing is done by setting layout_width to 0 and layout_height 0.